# GWT Designer produced code

Tags: gwt, gwt2, gwt-designer

I'm trying to understand GWT and its associated Designer plugin better.  Using one of the more recent versions of GWT Designer and GWT 2.* in your application, can you give me a sense for

1) how much additional (UI) code you needed to develop by hand (outside GWT Designer), perhaps as a rough percentage?  Was this code generally doing the model interface and controller part of MVC?

2) how well were you able to go between "design and code view"  -- i.e. keep using GWT Designer for your GUI layout after you supplemented with hand-written code?

Answer (score 1):

1) It does a lot like it generates html code, and ui:fields and binds the ui:field with a variable in java class. You have to write to your handlers. It does the model interface and controller done by hands.

2) To me it took a lot of time to switch views, to me the designer's performance was poor and I try to finish nt work inside the designer before switching to code view.

Comment: Thanks Shamaila.  I didn't understand #2 totally: are you saying that you could not easily switch back and forth between design and code views after adding in the controller code?